# what is IntegerProperty and why does it need to be imported

Tags: java, javafx, javabeans

So in class we always use the following syntax. Correct me if i am wrong but this is a bean because it class use getters/setters. It has an nullary constructor and the class implements serializable.

```
// option 1

private int customerID ;

public CustomerDTO ()
{
   this(0);
}

public CustomerDTO(int customerID) {
    setCustomerID(customerID);
}

public void setCustomerID(int customerID) {
    this.customerID = customerID;
}

public int getCustomerID() {
    return customerID;
}
```

But today i came across something similar like this. i needed to import

```
 import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
```

But what is the main difference between option 1 and 2.
When should i use option 1 or option 2 
And which one is better or does it depends on the situation.

```
// option 2
private final IntegerProperty customerID;

public CustomerDTO ()
{
   this(null);
}

public CustomerDTO(IntegerProperty customerID) {
    this.customerID =  new SimpleIntegerProperty(); 
}

public IntegerProperty getCustomerID() {
    return customerID;
}

  public void setCustomerID(int customerID) {
    this.customerID.set(customerID);
}
```

Comment: Your question should be: what is IntegerProperty and why it needs import, otherwise it makes no sense to ask about beans, go and read about them your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is used when you are building JavaFX application and want to bind your model with gui.

Example:

```
public class Foo {
    private final StringProperty foo = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo.get();
    }

    public StringProperty fooProperty() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo.set(foo);
    }
}

public class FooController {
    @FXML
    private TextField fooTextField;

    private final Foo foo = new Foo();

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        foo.fooProperty().bindBidirectional(fooTextField.textProperty());
    }
}
```

Comment: So a class does not to be option 1 or 2. I only need to make StringProperty if i use a fxml component. But say i would get the id from a database i can use option 1?

Comment: Use JavaFX properties when you need binding model with gui (or other binding). Are you building JavaFX app now? I think for you option 1 is right choice.

Answer (score 0):

`public CustomerDTO(IntegerProperty customerID) {` makes no sense, a `property` is a `final` class member which encapsulates a `value`, this value can be set via setters and get via setters, in JavaFX controller classes it is advisable to also implement a getter for the [ReadOnlyObjectProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyObjectProperty.html) or [ReadOnlyIntegerProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyIntegerProperty.html) in your case, this can be done via [ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.html) and its [getReadOnlyProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.html#getReadOnlyProperty()) method. This enables the developor to bind to values from other classes whilst also ensuring that the value exists at any time, JavaFX [Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) are a pretty elegant and object-oriented method of data-encapsulation.

Your "option 2" actually is flawed since it allows property-redefinition which  breaks this concept and makes the property itself useless. It will also break GUI functionality except if the property itself can not be redefined, see the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It all makes a bit more sense now.